# constantly get the current position of a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I would like to know how I can constantly get the current position of a mobile phone (latitude and longitude) using JavaScript.

Basically, when the phone is in a certain area I would like to start a timer. If the phone gets out of a certain area, the timer needs to stop. To do that, I need to constantly check each second, if the user is still in that area.
This is the code that I'm using to get the user's position:

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

}else{
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}

function showPosition(position) {
setInterval(function(){
lng = position.coords.longitude;
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    geo.innerHTML="Latitude: " + lat +"<br>Longitude:" + lng;


    myXhr.open("get", "Geo.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng, true);
    myXhr.send();}, 1000);

}
```

Moreover, when I tested it on my phone and I moved around a room, the coordinates did not change at all.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: Exactly how precise is your latitude and longitude reading? Moving around a room isn't going to give you a new latitude/longitude if you only go to 1 or 2 decimal places.

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition instead of polling getCurrentPosition().  also, GPS doesn't really work inside a room, it needs to see the satellites in the sky...

Comment: Hi @Adosi, I would like it to be extremely precise. The latitude and longitude I get offers me 6 digits after the decimal place.

Comment: @dandavis, I've used watchPosition() previously and I still have the same issue..